# Why are my labels and entry's not visible in python tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

This a a segment for my code creating a register screen, when run it creates no errors, however none of the labels or entry's are visible on the GUI, only the two buttons are visible on the tkinter window. Another frame i have uses exactly the same method to enter data, and works fine. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

```
 class register(Frame):
        def __init__(self,master):
            super().__init__(master)

            self.labelEmail = Label(self, text="Enter email:")
            self.labelUsername = Label(self,text="Enter username:")
            self.labelPassword = Label(self, text ="Enter password:")
            self.labelPassword2 = Label(self, text ="Re-enter password:")

            self.entryEmail = Entry(self)
            self.entryUsername = Entry(self)
            self.entryPassword = Entry(self, show="*")
            self.entryPassword2 = Entry(self, show="*")

            self.labelEmail.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
            self.labelUsername.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
            self.labelPassword.grid(row=2, sticky=E)
            self.labelPassword2.grid(row=3, sticky=E)

            self.entryEmail.grid(row=0, column=1)
            self.entryUsername.grid(row=1, column=1)
            self.entryPassword.grid(row=2, column=1)
            self.entryPassword2.grid(row=3, column=1)

            self.confirmBtn = Button(text="Confirm", command=self.confirmBtnClicked)
            self.confirmBtn.grid(row=4, column=0)


            self.cancelBtn = Button(text="Cancel",command=self.cancelBtnClicked)
            self.cancelBtn.grid(row=4, column=1)

    .....

    root = Tk()
    ls = register(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The instance of `register` class is the `Frame` and should be `self.grid`ed too.

Comment: @CommonSense that's the answer, make an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your class inherits from `Frame` and you are assigning your widgets to `self` (The Frame) you will need to also assign the Frame to the root window.

To do this you will need to add the line:

```
self.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Or:

```
self.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
# If you select this option you will need to use pack()
# for anything else you assign to the root window.
```

As Bryan pointed out in the comments a better solutions would be to call `grid()` or `pack()` when the class instance is created:

```
ls = register(root)
ls.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Comment: Another, arguably better solution is to call `pack` or `grid` in the context that creates it (ie: `ls = register(root); ls.pack(fill="both", expand=True)`)

Comment: Your call to `pack` should explicitly set the `fill` and `expand` options so that it behaves properly when the window is resized.

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks for the info. I have updated my answer to include your advice on this.